# AWS API Gateway - access internally

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-api-gateway

Although this question may seem like something you've seen in the past - please ensure to read it before assuming - as this is related to a different type of internal access.

We currently have a few `API Gateways`, serving different needs. These Gateways are public (regional) and accessed via public consumers.

On an ah-hoc basis, we do back-end releases, which entail removing the Gateway for external (public) access. The process is then, to make all deployments needed and then test the Gateway once public again.

- We go "internal" but adding the current `load balance(s)` into a group that's only accessible via internal IP range.

I'd like to know if there would be a way whereby we could access the same Gateway internally, whilst we are `offline`, to help speed up testing once back to external.

Comment: Hi..while we encourage you to involve in the community, please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways can be to use a WAF. You can automate the process to change the rule to be open only for you or to the world using. `IP Match Condition` rule can be useful for whitelisting.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-api-gateway-adds-support-for-aws-waf/

Answer (score 1):

You can have Ip based access for your API gateway.
There's a blog I found, that could be useful to you.
https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/04/14/amazon-api-gateway-ip-whitelisting/

Comment: Sounds interesting, I've up-voted the useful answers and will mark the one used, when we get to implementing this.